# Add control to TreeNode and get value from that

Tags: asp.net, treeview, controls, treenode

I would like to Add a DropDownList to TreeView for each node and then I will get the value when I click a button.Is there any way to do like that.Let me know the way you know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be helpful

http://forums.asp.net/t/1078228.aspx